# Is Aimi Yoshida the daughter of Sunfire?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Back in 2011, a company known as Silicon Knights released a game called X-Men: Destiny.

This game focused on playing as one of three characters:

- **Aimi Yoshida,** who feels that her father abandoned her.
- **Grant Alexander,** who is an aspiring football star.
- **Adrian Luca**, who is the son of a deceased anti-mutant Purifier.

However, one thing in the game remains unclear:

**Is Aimi Yoshida the daughter of the X-Man Sunfire?**

These three things below make me wonder:

1. **The Name:** Sunfire's real name in the comics was Shiro Yoshida, and in the game Aimi's last name is Yoshida.
2. **The Power Displayed When Aimi's Father Leaves:** In the comics, Sunfire is shown to have many fire-like abilities, and when Aimi's father leaves her, he is shown turning his body into flames.
3. **Aimi's Father Knew Nightcrawler:** When talking to Mystique and Nightcrawler, one of the main things that pop up is Kurt telling Aimi "I knew your father; he was a good man."